# How to put an input section in front of .bss in a linker script?

Tags: ld, linker-scripts

One of my ELF .o files have section named `.mybss` (similar to `.bss`). I'd like to put the contents of this section to the beginning of the output section `.bss`. What should I pass to GNU ld(1)?

Probably I have to write a linker script. I don't want to write a full one, I just want to extend the default one. Here is the relevant snippet from the default linker script:

```
SECTIONS {
  ...
  .bss : {
    *(.dynbss) *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*) *(COMMON)
    . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 32 / 8 : 1);
  }
  ...
}
```

I'd like to change this to:

```
SECTIONS {
  ...
  .mybss : { *(.mybss) }
  .bss : {
    *(.dynbss) *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*) *(COMMON)
    . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 32 / 8 : 1);
  }
  ...
}
```

This is **not** what I want:

```
SECTIONS {
  ...
  .bss : {
    *(.mybss) *(.dynbss) *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*) *(COMMON)
    . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 32 / 8 : 1);
  }
  ...
}
```